Both of NASA's ARED devices have a sign with the acronym "PLEASE;" what does it stand for?
I found two relevant PDFs (ARED Man-In-The-Loop Test) and (Mechanism Development, Testing, and Lessons Learned for the
Advanced Resistive Exercise Device), but they don't have the answer.
It is present on both the ISS and Ground versions of ARED, as shown by these images:
Ground version:

ISS version:



Pins in
Load to 0
Exit Ared
Straps
Equipment stow

Visible at full resolution here https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/iss038e002180/iss038e002180~orig.jpg

